# Show both formula and result

Tags: formula, openoffice-calc

I am having a formula in Cell D9 and I want to put the result of this formula in Cell G9. Please note that I want formula showing in cell D9, and cell G9 should contain the result of formula written in D9.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the **[`FORMULA()`](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#FORMULA)** function. Move your current formula from D9 to G9 (take care to preserve the cell references), and put `=FORMULA(G9)` into the now empty D9. As result, D9 will show the formula and G9 the result.